# open a python file in pythonwin from command line and set focus to a particular line

Tags: python-winshell

from c#, I need to open a file in pythonwin and set the cursor to a particular code area or line number

I haveopened the file in pythonwin by giving file path as parameter to the pythonwin exe .. but don't know how to set the cursor

Comment: Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\Pythonwin.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"D:\Invoker.py;
p.Start();